# ¿Cómo pasar datos de un screen a otro en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

necesito saber como pasar un dato de un screen a otro screen. En mi código, específicamente el código que necesito en otro screen, sería myData, en el otro screen quiero colocar la opción de agregar a esa variable myData.

Puesto que necesito que el otro screen sea para añadir, modificar y actualizar datos, los cuales irán almacenados en myData

```
Center(

    child: FutureBuilder(
      future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/locals.json'),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        var myData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());

        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[

            Image.asset('assets/telemovil.png'),
            Text('ASISTENTE RV MONITOREO', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                height: media.height * 0.55,
                width: media.width * 0.8,

                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 7,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index){
                    return CardItemLocal(
                      textLocal: myData[index]['Lugar'].toString(),
                      textLat: myData[index]['Latitud'].toString(),
                      textLong: myData[index]['Longitud'].toString(),
                      iconoA: IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                        print(myData);
                        final data1 = ClipboardData(text: myData[index]['Latitud'].toString(),);
                        Clipboard.setData(data1); 
                        },
                        tooltip: 'Copiado al Portapales',
                        icon: Icon(Icons.computer)
                      ),
                      iconoB: IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          final data2 = ClipboardData(text: myData[index]['Longitud'].toString(),);
                          Clipboard.setData(data2);

                        },
                        tooltip: 'Copiado al Portapales',
                        icon: Icon(Icons.computer)
                      ),
                    );
                    //Text(myData[index]['Lugar']);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Lo siento pero tu pregunta no se entiende. Los puntos y las comas existen para algo.

Comment: tiene puntos y comas! Al parecer es mejor para algunos criticar y quitar puntos que ayudar a mejorar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo que leas la documentación oficial de Flutter

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: todos.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(todos[index].title),
      // When a user taps the ListTile, navigate to the DetailScreen.
      // Notice that you're not only creating a DetailScreen, you're
      // also passing the current todo to it.
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => DetailScreen(todo: todos[index]),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Gracias! @diegoveloper